# Group activerecord relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

After a select on a table I get a result:

```
[#<Result url: "http://www.url.com/1", key_id: 1>, 
#<Result url: "http://www.url.com/1", key_id: 2> [...]
```

How can I group the `url` and keep the `key_id`, something like:

```
["http://www.url.com/1", [1, 2]]=>2
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
grouped_results = Result.all.group_by(&:url).map do |url, results|
  { [url, results.map(&:key_id)] => results.count }
end
```

You need to replace `Result.all` by your actual scope or something.